# Google Flex App Engine instance with GCP Free Tier, is it possible?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

maybe I’ve screwed up,

I’ve deployed an app to a Flex GCP App Engine, but then while I was reading the GCP Free Trial, I’ve discovered that I cannot use the flex instance (yeah I know, I should have read it before), now I’ve disabled it from the console, but I was wondering if I can get some kind of billing directly on my credit card and not on the free credit.

I’ve tried to ask directly tho the GCP assistance, but the chat session doesn’t start.

Answer (score -1):

Getting credits directly  on your credit card indicates [upgrading your GCP account](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) from the free trial to a paid account through the Google Cloud Console. To do so,  click the **Activate** button. If the **Activate** button is not visible, on the menu bar, click **Free trial status** and the **Activate** button will appear.

> To take advantage of the features of a paid account (using GPUs, for
>   example), you can upgrade before the trial ends. When you upgrade, the
>   following conditions apply:
>
> - Any remaining, unexpired free trial credit remains in your account.
> - Your credit card on file is charged for resources you use in excess of
>     what's covered by any remaining credit.
>
> You can upgrade your account
>   at any time after starting the free trial. The following conditions
>   apply depending on when you upgrade:
>
> - If you upgrade before the trial is over, your remaining credit is
>     added to your paid account. You can continue to use the resources you
>     created during the free trial without interruption.
> - If you upgrade within 30 days of the end of the trial, you can restore
>     the resources you created during the trial.
> - If you upgrade more than 30 days after the end of the trial, your free
>     trial resources are lost.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits), you may find the list of resources of GCP that can be *Always Free* and available.

Furthermore, [here](http://]https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#create-budget) you may find information on how to handle your budget, set up alerts and notifications for proper management.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/support/billing) tells you how to contact Cloud Billing Support if you need help with your Cloud Billing account, and shows you where to get more information about managing your billing account. In addition to that, [here](https://cloud.google.com/support#support-plans) you may find all the Customer Care Support plans that Google offers.

I hope this information helps.

**EDIT:**

As stated [here](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#exceed-always-free):

> Any usage above Always Free usage limits is automatically billed at standard rates.

Thus, you will be charged for the usage of that GAE Flex instance.

Additionally, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-pricing) you can check Flexible environment pricing details and [here](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/reports) you have the information about viewing your billing reports.

Comment: Thanks for his detailed response, so if I had the Free Tier, they wouldn't get my money, am I right?
Because the "Google Cloud Free Tier" says: 'The Google Cloud Free Tier is available only for the Standard Environment.', so the flex environment is not allowed, and for this reason, they should take my "real" money, am I wrong?

Comment: I have edited my answer to reply to your comment, also providing additional info. (Find "EDIT:" section at the end of my answer) If the answer was adequate, please kindly accept it for future visibility on this post.